# Flickering AVPlayerLayer when passing between UIView & UIViewController

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm creating my custom video player with fullscreen capabilities. When the user taps the fullscreen button I pass my AVPlayerLayer to the UIViewController and back when exiting fullscreen. Entering fullscreen works fine, but when I leave the fullscreen state and pass the AVPlayerLayer back to the UIView (inside a UITableViewCell) the layer disappears / flickers once.

I'm removing/adding the layer with the following code:

```
playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

Commenting the `playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()` doesn't change anything and it still flickers.

I also tried not to reuse the same AVPlayerLayer and create a second one for the UIViewController, but then both are out of sync when switching states.

Any help would be appreciated!